# Python removing repetitions using list(set(v)) changes array order

Tags: python, list

I've the following array with multiple repetitions and I want to remove them mantaining the order.

```
v = ['maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega']
```

I use `list(set(v))` and I get the following output:
`['embega', 'maier', 'tapa pure']`

What I want to have is to remove the repetition, but maintain the original order:
 `['maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega']`

I cant use `v[:3]` because the repetitions length is variable.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
seen_items = set()
w = [] 
for item in v:
    if item not in seen_items:
        w.append(item)
        seen_items.add(item)
```

Comment: the way you do it, the set() is unnecessary. seen_items could be a list too and nothing would change. Actually you could write `if item not in w; w.append(item)`

Comment: Search in a list would be O(n) compared to O(1) for a set.

Comment: ok in that you're correct.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)'s `fromkeys` function, like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print OrderedDict.fromkeys(v).keys()
# ['maier', 'tapa pure', 'embega']
```